# Ambiguous column reference in hive

Tags: hive

I am trying to find the average of "seconds" from the below query. I get the error "Ambiguous column reference date_time in t".

I am not sure on how to resolve it. Any suggestions would be great !!

```
 select dayname(tc.date_time), sum(seconds) from (
  select td.visid, td.visid1, td.num, concat(td.visid, td.visid1, td.num) as session,td.date_time, tc.date_time,
  second(tc.date_time) - second(td.date_time) as seconds
  from tb1 as td 
  join tb2 as tc
  on td.visid = tc.visid and  td.visid1 = tc.visid1 and td.num = tc.num and
  td.name = 'Detail' and tc.name = 'Confirm'
  where td.date_time between "2017-05-01 00:00:00" and "2017-07-31 00:00:00") as t
  group by dayname(tc.date_time);
```

Comment: td.date_time and tc.date_time will both be listed as columns named "date_time." You need to select them "as" (exactly like how you did session)

Answer (score 0):

same column name date_time in both tables is creating problem. Give alias for both of these column. this will solve your problem.

```
   select dayname(t.a), sum(t.seconds) from (
  select td.visid, td.visid1, td.num, concat(td.visid, td.visid1, td.num) as session,td.date_time as d, tc.date_time as a,
  second(tc.date_time) - second(td.date_time) as seconds
  from tb1 as td 
  join tb2 as tc
  on td.visid = tc.visid and  td.visid1 = tc.visid1 and td.num = tc.num and
  td.name = 'Detail' and tc.name = 'Confirm'
  where td.date_time between "2017-05-01 00:00:00" and "2017-07-31 00:00:00") as t
  group by dayname(t.a);
```